# Typedef/struct declarations

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What is the difference between these two declarations, if someone could explain in detail:

```
typedef struct atom {
  int element;
  struct atom *next;
};
```

and

```
typedef struct {
  int element;
  struct atom *next;
} atom;
```

Comment: Check difference [one](http://codepad.org/BFWrrQET) and [two](http://codepad.org/aV0Dpf8z), in first [typedef is redundant](http://codepad.org/zfvEXthM)

Comment: The first one is not valid. The whole point of `typedef` is to give a new name to a type declaration, and you haven't given any name to the structure type.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Kind of raises more questions than it answers.

Comment: @Barmar I'm kind of a beginner in C so if you could explain it a bit more 'plain'. I understood typedef was meant to avoid having to type struct every time you created a new struct~.

I was going after the fact struct with name before the braces specifies a type and name after braces specifies a "variable" with that name, I thought it applied to typedef struct too, obviously I've made a serious thinking error here somewhere.

Comment: Why @Barmar ? Why is it redundant?

Comment: Why what? I never said redundant, that was Grijesh Chauhan. @user129393192

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The purpose of `typedef` is to give a name to a type specification. The syntax is:

```
typedef <specification> <name>;
```

After you've done that, you can use `<name>` much like any of the built-in types of the language to declare variables.

In your first example, you the `<specification>` is everything starting with `struct atom`, but there's no `<name>` after it. So you haven't given a new name to the type specification.

Using a name in a `struct` declaration is not the same as defining a new type. If you want to use that name, you always have to precede it with the `struct` keyword. So if you declare:

```
struct atom {
    ...
};
```

You can declare new variables with:

```
struct atom my_atom;
```

but you can't declare simply

```
atom my_atom;
```

For the latter, you have to use `typedef`.

Note that this is one of the notable differences between C and C++. In C++, declaring a `struct` or `class` type *does* allow you to use it in variable declarations, you don't need a `typedef`. `typedef` is still useful in C++ for other complex type constructs, such as function pointers.

You should probably look over some of the questions in the **Related** sidebar, they explain some other nuances of this subject.

Comment: Oh, that explains it, it more related to typedef than to struct.

One other question; whats the deal when there is a a word at both places:

`code`

typedef struct at {
int element;
struct at *next;
} atom;

Comment: That allows you to use either `struct at` or `atom` to declare variables.

Comment: Meaning this is the sole purpose of this?

Comment: You need to give the `struct` a name so that you can reference it in the `next` link, because the `typedef` isn't defined until after the statement.

Comment: See this question regarding typedef and linked lists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988041/struct-containing-pointers-to-itself

Answer (score 22):

This is Normal `structure declaration`

```
  struct atom {
      int element;
      struct atom *next;
    };    //just declaration
```

creation of `object`

```
 struct atom object;
```

---

```
  struct atom {
      int element;
      struct atom *next;
    }object;    //creation of object along with structure declaration
```

---

And

This is Type definition of  `struct atom` type

```
typedef  struct atom {
  int element;
  struct atom *next;
}atom_t;  //creating new type
```

Here `atom_t` is alias for `struct atom`

creation of object

```
atom_t object;      
struct atom object; //both the ways are allowed and same
```

Comment: `typedef` is a keyword . The purpose of typedef is to form complex types from more-basic machine types.SEE THIS INFO typedef      http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax of typedef keyword will be: 
`typedef existing_data_type new_data_type;`

```
typedef struct Record {
    char ename[30];
     int ssn;
    int deptno;
} employee;
```