# C Programming -> Linked lists and structs

Tags: c, linux, pointers

So I have the following located in a .h file

```
typedef struct Supply {
      char* name;
      struct Supply* nextSupply;
      int quantity;
 } Supply;
```

And the following

```
typedef struct Location {
      Supply* firstSupply;
 } Location;
```

And I want to use it in a snippet such as this in a c file where the h file is included

```
void snippet(Location* location, Supply* incoming) {
    Supply* first = location->firstSupply;
    Supply* check = first->nextSupply;
    if(!strcmp(first->name,incoming->name) {
          *some stuff*
    }
    *while loop checking entire linked list*
}
```

Why is it that I am told by gcc -Wall -pedantic that I am assigning from invalid pointer types. I understand that in definition of Supply I must refer to the nextSupply as a struct Supply* but I thought after the definition is finished then Supply* == struct Supply*

Comment: This doesn't look like it's your actual code, e.g. `if(!strcmp(first->name,incoming->name) {` will not even compile as-is ? Please copy and paste *actual code* rather than an approximation (although it's OK to trim stuff out of course).

Comment: I think your idea about it is right, you must have another type of error. But since you are not showing us your whole code, we can't figure this out.

Comment: I very much doubt that as the c compiler identifies only the lines I have shown to you as evidence of assigning to an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think this is related to your problem. The very fisrt answer should
>   fix the deal.
>
> [How to define a typedef struct containing pointers to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988041/struct-containing-pointers-to-itself][1])

From my perception it is a struct defenition scope issue. Meaning that, the struct definition must be within scope before variables of that type can be declared.

So the work around would be a forward declaration, which is a declaration of your struct, which you would define later in your code:

```
typedef struct Supply Supply ;

typedef struct Supply {
      char* name;
      struct Supply* nextSupply;
      int quantity;
 } Supply;
```

Comment: **The very fisrt answer should fix the deal.** you must paste that answer here, the link may be dead later point.

Comment: Yes, link only answers are frowned upon, and actually I don't think that the thinks described there answer the question.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Got to be more detailed next time.

Comment: This resolved the issue. I wasn't aware you could typedef prior to setting up the struct. Very useful.