# How do I reference a value from a variable from a pointer from a pointer?

Tags: c, variables, pointers, struct, compiler-errors

I have a struct:

```
 struct room;
 ...
 /*some more structs */

 typedef struct {     
   int state;
   int id;
   struct room* north;
   struct room* south;
   struct room* east;
   struct room* west;
   creature* creatures[10];
 } room;
```

And a function that prints the contents:

```
 void printContentsOfRoom(room* r) {
   printf("\nRoom %d:\n", r->id);
   printf("\tState: %s\n", getState(r));
   printf("\n\tNeighbors:\n");
   if (r->north.id != -1)
     printf("\t    North: Room %d\n",((room*)r->north)->id);
   if (r->east.id != -1)
     printf("\t    East: Room %d\n",((room*)r->east)->id);
   if (r->south.id != -1)
     printf("\t    South: Room %d\n",((room*)r->south)->id);
   if (r->west.id != -1)
     printf("\t    West: Room %d\n",((room*)r->west)->id);
   printf("\n\tCreatures:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     creature* c = (creature*)r->creatures[i];
     if (c) {
       if (c == pc)
     printf("\t    %s\n",getType(c));
       else
     printf("\t    %s %d\n",getType(c),c->id);
     }
   }
 }
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the room id is set to -1 (set while the program runs), it does not print the information about that room. On compilation, I get the error "request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union."

Furthermore, I have tried setting the if condition r->north->id, and that returns the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct room'"

Comment: `typedef struct {` --> `typedef struct room {` then  `r->north->id`

Comment: Don't use casts if you don't have understood the problem!

Comment: `r->west` is a pointer, right? `.` only works on structs and unions, and a pointer is not a struct or union. So `r->west.anything` is invalid. But you could use `(*r->west).anything`, or `r->west->anything` for short.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to do a forward declaration like this:

```
typedef struct room room;

struct room{
    .
    .
    .
};
```

Then you can use `r->north->id`. See this SO question: [How to define a typedef struct containing pointers to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988041/how-to-define-a-typedef-struct-containing-pointers-to-itself)