# How do you use a typedef in a struct for which the struct is defining?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, typedef

If I have this:

```
typedef struct {
   foo_t *bar;
} foo_t;
```

then I get errors like `error: unknown type name ‘foo_t’`. I could make bar a void* and cast later, but that seems like the wrong way to go.

Is there a proper way to resolve this chicken and egg problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [self referential struct definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588623/self-referential-struct-definition) or [How to define a typedef struct containing pointers to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988041/364696) The second is the more exact duplicate (just found the first one earlier, and it's similar). I actually prefer the second solution to the second link (using the `struct` name, not the `typedef` name within the struct definition), but either works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
   typedef struct foo_t {
       struct foo_t *bar;
   } foo;
```

So your type is foo, which is the same as struct foo_t

Comment: That works.  As it turns out, the typedef and struct can both be named foo_t so I don't have two names floating around.